# Background service in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk, background-process

By my search background service is not supported in corona SDK. But i need that feature.so any one please suggest other solution or any other possibility to do.i need location detail at every minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in Corona as their focus is game development. You should use the enterprise version and use their native extension capability. One option will be to develop a basic app in the native platform and they will trigger your app.
https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/40766-background-service/